# How to Integrate Non-Gregorian Calendars in Calendar Module?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, datetime

I plan to create a simple event calendar on Drupal 7 that uses the Arabic Calendar (Hijri) instead of Gregorian (western) calendar. Instead of developing a new module, I was wondering if I can use the capabilities of Calendar Module and make it use Hijri Calendar instead of Georgian calendar in views and in the calendar template. The mini-calendar should be Hijri Calendar. No need for Month or Year calendars.

There is a module called [Calendar Systems](http://drupal.org/project/calendar_systems) that adds the support of Hijri Calendar to Drupal but I'm not sure how it can be integrated with the Calendar Module or Views.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest development snapshot of the Calendar Systems module. It works fine.

Comment: dev version is not recommended.

Comment: There have since been releases so you can now use the beta5 release.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently [not possible](http://drupal.org/node/166234). However, the calendar systems module appears to be working on [Views integration](http://drupal.org/node/721590), but unfortunately for D6. There's some code there that you might be able to use.

The Calendar module issue that I have linked to also links to a wiki page where you can participate in discussions on this subject.

Comment: Thank you Coleopterist. So my only option is to create custom module?

Comment: I think that it's best that you work with the Calendar systems maintainers to improve the module and get it to a final release. I'm sure that there are a number of other people out there who want calendar variants as well - get in touch with them via Drupal groups and the issue queue and drum up support and resources. I also recommend that you get in touch with farsi/arabic/hebrew localisation teams as they're likely to be interested as well. Good luck!